# Shoudl I create seperate column family if I want to query on many columns ? or use composite PK?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a column family like

> object
>       (
>       obect_id,
>       company-id,
>       group_id,
>       family_id,
>       description,
>       ..
>       );

I want to query that based on object id, company id ,group id and any combination of these.

My question is
should i make composite primary key

> (object id, company id ,group id)

or create seperate column familis ?

only object id is unique in CF, company id can repeat in multiple rows, but group iddoes not repeat in many rows

Answer (score 1):

You may well want to duplicate your data in multiple CFs depending on your query patterns. This is quite common practice.

If a common query is "Get all objects by company_id" then you might want to store all objects with in a CF with partitioned just by company_id as a row key. If you need to do individual object lookups as well, then you store that data duplicated in another CF - each object partitioned by object_id. If groups are always a subset of a specific company, perhaps you want to row key by company, but then cluster by group.

You should be designing your Cassandra schema based on the queries you need to run, rather than the data that needs to go in it.